# Update field in Table when conditions fulfilled in MS Access 2013

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2010, ms-access-2013

I have two tables in MS Access 2013.

### Table of SERVICE:

(ID is the primary key)

```
ID PART_ID SERVICE_DATE REMARK WITHDRAWN
1   A0001   01/04/2014 
2   A0002   01/04/2014
3   A0003   01/04/2014  SCRAP
4   A0004   01/04/2014
5   A0001   01/05/2014
6   A0002   01/05/2014
```

### Table of WITHDRAW:

(ID is the primary key)

```
ID PART_ID DRAW_DATE
1   A0001  02/04/2014
2   A0002  02/04/2014
3   A0001  02/05/2014
```

I'd like to put a "**NO**" into the field of **WITHDRAWN** in Table of SERVICE to indicate the part has not been withdraw yet, if:

> 1. Part is first time in Table of SERVICE and never appear in Table of WITHDRAW.
> 2. Part appears few times in Table of SERVICE and Table of WITHDRAW, already serviced this time, not withdraw yet.
> 3. Part is not under category of "SCRAP".

### Targetted Result:

Table of SERVICE

```
ID PART_ID SERVICE_DATE REMARK WITHDRAWN
1   A0001   01/04/2014 
2   A0002   01/04/2014
3   A0003   01/04/2014  SCRAP
4   A0004   01/04/2014            NO
5   A0001   01/05/2014
6   A0002   01/05/2014            NO
```

But I just know how to write the code for the first condition:

```sql
UPDATE SERVICE LEFT JOIN WITHDRAW ON SERVICE.PART_ID = WITHDRAW.PART_ID SET SERVICE.WITHDRAWN = "NO" WHERE WITHDRAW.PART_ID Is Null;
```

Can somebody amend my code so that I can achieve the targetted result? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is the following query:

```
UPDATE service 
       LEFT JOIN withdraw 
              ON service.part_id = withdraw.part_id 
                 AND service.service_date <= withdraw.draw_date 
SET    service.withdrawn = "no" 
WHERE  withdraw.part_id IS NULL 
       AND Nz(service.remark, "") <> "scrap";
```

Your rules where a bit hard to understand, but I think I got it. I threw rule 1 and 2 together as follows:

> 1.Part is first time in Table of SERVICE and never appear in Table of WITHDRAW.
>
> 2.Part appears few times in Table of SERVICE and Table of WITHDRAW, already serviced this time, not withdraw yet.

==> The service_date of the part must be greater than the last withdraw_date for every part.

Comment: You're GREAT!!! I have been cracked my head in this solution for few weeks already. Thank you so much!